# Replace string to null

Tags: java, string, kotlin, replace, null

I have a string like

`{"id":"1","name":"BAG","status":"A","account_id":"null"}`

I want to change the string "null" to null. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: do you want to convert it to a object to do that or just edit it raw as string?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I would like to convert it to an object as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
src.replace("\"null\"", "null")
```

?

Here's a executable example: https://pl.kotl.in/O013YFFrO

Comment: @GabLedesma feel free to accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: That's likely to fail if the object has a field called `null`, or a value whose representation includes `"null"` (e.g. the string `"abc\"null"`).  The only completely safe solution would be to deserialise/parse the JSON (after all, this is clearly a JSON object), manipulate the resulting object tree, and then re-serialise it — best done using a JSON library.